# Why does assigning names to widgets in my onCreate method give an error, but works when I assign them in another method?

Tags: java, android, null

I currently have my onCreate method immediately calling the method question1 that assigns the names of all the widgets. Everything works in the method question1, but when I call the method question2, I get a NullPointerException.

Here's the crash log:

```
06-05 18:10:23.468    2223-2223/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2223 SIG: 9
06-05 18:11:42.705    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
06-05 18:11:42.708    2291-2291/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa68404f0, tid 2291
06-05 18:11:42.748    2291-2291/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-05 18:11:42.814    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6840590, tid 2306
06-05 18:11:42.846    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-05 18:11:42.876    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-05 18:11:42.900    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-05 18:11:42.900    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa682fe20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-05 18:11:43.172    2291-2303/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 411(66KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 52% free, 922KB/1946KB, paused 11.415ms total 57.104ms
06-05 18:11:46.795    2291-2303/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1071(71KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 8.748ms total 63.358ms
06-05 18:11:46.944    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-05 18:11:46.944    2291-2306/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5cf5480, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-05 18:11:51.743    2291-2291/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 283 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-05 18:11:58.298    2291-2291/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-05 18:11:58.298    2291-2291/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview, PID: 2291
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.RadioButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference
            at com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview.QuizActivity$1.onClick(QuizActivity.java:55)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-05 18:12:00.192    2291-2291/com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2291 SIG: 9
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.nordicstewdios.presidentreview;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int question = 1;
    private int answersWrong = 0;

    private TextView textViewQuestion;
    private TextView textViewWrong;

    private RadioButton radioButton1;
    private RadioButton radioButton2;
    private RadioButton radioButton3;
    private RadioButton radioButton4;

    private Button buttonNextQ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        question1();

    }

    private void question1(){
        final TextView textViewQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
        final TextView textViewWrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWrong);

        final RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        final RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        final RadioButton radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        final RadioButton radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        final Button buttonNextQ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNextQ);

        buttonNextQ.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(!radioButton1.isChecked() && !radioButton2.isChecked() && !radioButton3.isChecked() && !radioButton4.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Choose an option before continuing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                else if(radioButton1.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    question++;
                    question2();

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    answersWrong++;
                    textViewWrong.setText("Answers Wrong: " + answersWrong);
                }

            }
        });

    }
    private void question2(){
        textViewQuestion.setText("What was the second president, and what were his terms?");
        radioButton1.setText("John Adams, 1797 - 1805");
        radioButton2.setText("Thomas Jefferson, 1797 - 1801");
        radioButton3.setText("Thomas Jefferson, 1797 - 1805");
        radioButton4.setText("John Adams, 1797 - 1801");

        buttonNextQ.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(!radioButton1.isChecked() && !radioButton2.isChecked() && !radioButton3.isChecked() && !radioButton4.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Choose an option before continuing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else if(radioButton1.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    question++;
                    //question3();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    answersWrong++;
                    textViewWrong.setText("Answers Wrong: " + answersWrong);
                }

            }
        });
    }
    private void question3(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Your field variables are never assigned

Comment: @karaokyo I didn't assign the int field variables but I assigned the others

Comment: @karaokyo Thanks for clearing that up, I think that answered my question. I just have to assign all of the variables in each different method.

Comment: That's not quite right

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring all the textviews and radiobuttons again in the question2 method.

```
private void question1(){
        textViewQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
        textViewWrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWrong);

        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        buttonNextQ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNextQ);

        buttonNextQ.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(!radioButton1.isChecked() && !radioButton2.isChecked() && !radioButton3.isChecked() && !radioButton4.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Choose an option before continuing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                else if(radioButton1.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    question++;
                    question2();

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    answersWrong++;
                    textViewWrong.setText("Answers Wrong: " + answersWrong);
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Try something like this.

Comment: Am I missing something? This looks like the code I already have.

Comment: Replace alla the "final TextView textViewQuestion = . . ." with "textViewQuestion = . . ." in the question1 method. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is to cache the variables in your `onCreate` as the `findViewById` operation is expensive:

```
public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int question = 1;
    private int answersWrong = 0;

    private TextView textViewQuestion;
    private TextView textViewWrong;

    private RadioButton radioButton1;
    private RadioButton radioButton2;
    private RadioButton radioButton3;
    private RadioButton radioButton4;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;

    private Button buttonNextQ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        textViewQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
        textViewWrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWrong);

        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        buttonNextQ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNextQ);

        question1();
    }

    private void question1(){
        buttonNextQ.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(!radioButton1.isChecked() && !radioButton2.isChecked() && !radioButton3.isChecked() && !radioButton4.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Choose an option before continuing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                else if(radioButton1.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    question++;
                    question2();

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    answersWrong++;
                    textViewWrong.setText("Answers Wrong: " + answersWrong);
                }

            }
        });

    }
    private void question2(){
        textViewQuestion.setText("What was the second president, and what were his terms?");
        radioButton1.setText("John Adams, 1797 - 1805");
        radioButton2.setText("Thomas Jefferson, 1797 - 1801");
        radioButton3.setText("Thomas Jefferson, 1797 - 1805");
        radioButton4.setText("John Adams, 1797 - 1801");

        buttonNextQ.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(!radioButton1.isChecked() && !radioButton2.isChecked() && !radioButton3.isChecked() && !radioButton4.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Choose an option before continuing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else if(radioButton1.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    question++;
                    //question3();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong Answer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    answersWrong++;
                    textViewWrong.setText("Answers Wrong: " + answersWrong);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That is giving me a NullPointerException when I try to create the button click listener.

Comment: Do you still have a null local variable? Or are you calling question1() before initializing your fields?